file drop sftp automation
I am using Cyberduck to access FTP.
Is there any possibility of detecting file drops when downloading files in FTP?
I have had an event where automation is triggered even though there is no evidence of a file being spit out.
I have downloaded FTP files to my PC desktop during that time period.
ファイルのアップロードが行われていないのにファイルドロップでオートメーションが開始されていました。
その時間にファイルのアップロードは行っていないのですが、FTPのファイルをPCのデスクトップにダウンロードは行いました。
ファイルのダウンロードを行うことでファイルドロップを検知してしまうことはありますか？

I don't really follow your question. Do you want an automation to trigger when a file is downloaded from SFMC FTP with e.g. Cyberduck?

File drop execution was recorded at an unexpected time.
I did not upload any files at that time, but I did download the FTP files to my PC desktop.
Automation was started on the file drop even though no file upload was performed.
その時間にファイルのアップロードは行っていないのですが、FTPのファイルをPCのデスクトップにダウンロードは行いました。
ファイルのアップロードが行われていないのにファイルドロップでオートメーションが開始されていました。
